# For $s(t) = a_2t^2 + a_1t + a_0$ and $r(t) = b_2t^2 + b_1t + b_0$ in $P_2[t],$ define $<s(t),r(t)> = 2a_2b_2 + a_1b_1 + 3a_0b_0$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

EDIT: I'm still trying to figure out! Will ask for help if I can't answer it still by the end of the day. Thank you :)

Online classes hasn't been as easy as face-to-face classes and with that my professor is quite old and isn't very familiar with the online methods of teaching these days.

He said that the above is an inner product on $P_2[t].$
In attempting to prove other < , > examples, I would like to know how to know and show that < , > are inner products on $P_2[t].$ You may use the example I provided. Thank you so much!

Comment: The obvious answer to your question would be to look up the definition of "inner product" and check the requirements listed there. I imagine you already did that, but if so then you should indicate which specific requirement caused difficulty and what the nature of the difficulty was.

Comment: Hello thank you for replying so quickly. I do understand the properties. However what I don't get is how I'll be able to prove them given the coefficients in < , > = 2___ + ___ + 3___ . I'm just simply at a loss since those coefficients seemed to come out of nowhere and I'm not sure how to show especially properties 2 & 3 (2 |  <s,r> = <r,s>) & (3 | <ap,q> = a<p,q>). Thank you again :)

Comment: The coefficients $2$ and $3$ do indeed come out of nowhere. Any two positive numbers would work just as well; that is, they'd also produce a (different) inner product. But these coefficients shouldn't cause any difficulty in checking the required properties of inner products.

Answer (score 1):

an orthonormal basis is given by
$$    \frac{t^2}{\sqrt 2}, \; \; \; t, \; \; \; \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}  $$

If you have real numbers with $$e^2 + f^2 + g^2 = 1,$$
a unit vector is given by
$$    \frac{ e t^2}{\sqrt 2} \; \; \; +ft + \; \; \; \frac{g}{\sqrt 3}  $$

The quadratic form is given by the norm of your $s(t)$ being
$$ 3 a_0^2 +  a_1^2 + 2 a_2^2  $$
which becomes $g^2 + f^2 + e^2 $ when $a_0 = g/ \sqrt 3, \; \; a_1 = f, \; \; a_2 = e/ \sqrt 2$

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I understand it a little better now. I just would like to ask if after showing a0, a1, a2, does this mean I can drop the "coefficients"  2___ + ___ + 3___ when proving each property of the inner product? 

for example: Property 2 <p,q> = <q,p>
From:
<q,p> = 2b0a0 + b1a1 + 3b2a2
           = 2a0b0 + a1b1 + 3a2b2

I can just show:
<q,p> = b0a0 + b1a1 + b2a2
           = a0b0 + a1b1 + a2b2

Since I already implied a0, a1, a2 in the beginning of the proving?

Comment: @Leb I'm not sure what to say; I am off for a bit, I guess I will check back later. If you edit in your improved version (in your question), maybe someone will notice it and give you more focused feedback.  For a quadratic form, given the Hessian  matrix $H$ of the given form, the Hessian under a new basis is given by $G = P^T H P.$ In your exapmple, $H$ was already diagonal, so we were able to change basis (columns of $P$) with $P$ diagonal, entries $1/\sqrt 3 , 1, 1/\sqrt 2$ in the $1,t,t^2$ order.